# Updating questions in a Rails form via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form that loops through some questions:

```
<%= form_for @assessment do |f| %>

   <div class="questions">
      <%= render 'questions', :f=> f %>
   </div>

<% end %>
```

questions partial:

```
  <div class="questions">
    <% @o_questions.each do |question| %>
       <%= render 'question_fields', :question=> question, :f=> f %>
    <% end %>
  </div
```

If the user clicks a "filter" button, I want to make an AJAX call to update the @o_questions variable that I loop through in the questions partial:

```
 <%= link_to "Tracked Questions", assessments_followups_answers_path(:assessment=> @original_assessment,  :filter=> "tracked_questions"), :class=>"btn btn-default filter active", :id=>"tracked", :remote=> true %>
```

Action (#answers)

```
if @filter == "tracked_questions"
  @s_questions = @original_assessment.tracked_questions("S")
end
```

Answers.js.erb:

```
$('.questions').html("<%= j render 'questions', :f => f %>");
```

So basically the idea is to re-render the questions partial with the new @o_questions variable. But I'm stumbling because I am getting the below error

```
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f'
> for #<#<Class:
```

How can I accomplish this? I don't think I can pass the form object through the controller. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: are data tags an option?  you can filter based on certain values in a data tag. It would save you an AJAX call to boot. I just to know the scope of your project to make an informed answer.

Comment: Yeah that's a great thought. I guess I was concerned it might be heavy to run so many loops in  the view.  I have 4 categories: S, O, A, and P. I loop 4 different times displaying questions in each of those categories. Then within those categories, I'd need to loop 3 times to assign data tags for my 3 filters... Is that too heavy?

Comment: I want to say no, it's not too heavy but I think it really depends on the nature of the objects you are iterating through and how many there are. It looks like you are only applying this action to a few of the selected questions. I am not a JavaScript guru by any means but you should be able to temporarily memoize the tracked questions and their associated DOM objects and filter based on that. I would try with JavaScript only first, if you are unhappy with your performance at some spinners to show that the browser is working. If that still takes to long consider using AJAX calls.